# How to add the title attribute manually to <a> tag

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/contextual-related-posts and I wanted to manually add the title attribute in each heading link. Right now only the image has the title attribute. Please help

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why do you want to do this? If the `<a>` is around text, the `title` attribute is not useful. Also, this would be really hard to answer since almost all WP sites are built differently depending on the developer/development team. Also, [for accessibility they are bad](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/title-attributes/)

Answer (score 0):

While the plugin may not provide a built-in option for this, you can achieve it by using custom JavaScript.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.crp_related').find('h3 a.crp_link').attr('title', 'Your Custom Title Here');
});
</script>
```

If you want to dynamically set the title attribute for each heading link based on its content, you can modify the JavaScript code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.crp_related').find('h3 a.crp_link').each(function() {
        var headingText = jQuery(this).text();
        jQuery(this).attr('title', headingText);
    });
});
</script>
```

**Note:** Please replace the heading tag according to your needs, and let me know if you have any confusion or issues.